# Single Sign-On extension for Magento and Socialengine

Tags: magento2

We have created a community website built in socialengine and an online store built in magento. Now I want to integrate the magento and socialengine using single sign on process. Is there any magento extension available for Single Sign-On between Magento and Socialengine ?

Comment: "Shopping list" questions are not a good fit for StackExchange Q&A
(see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-are-shopping-list-questions-bad) -
you'll get better results at the Magento forums (https://community.magento.com/t5/Find-an-Extension-that/bd-p/find-extension)
or Reddit (http://www.reddit.com/r/Magento)

Comment: I'm curious what is insufficient with the results that you find by searching Google for "Magento socialengine integration"?

Comment: An alternative is to use the SAML standard. Use the php-saml toolkit (https://github.com/onelogin/php-saml) in order to add SAML support to the socialengine app, use simplesamlphp () in order to deploy an Identity provider (https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-idp) using the socialengine database as authentication source and add SAML support to Magento2 by https://marketplace.magento.com/sixtomartin-onelogin-module-saml2.html.

The advantage of using SAML instead another tricky SSO mechanism are (let SSO between different domains, standard, already supported by many apps)

Answer (score 2):

we have implemented a solution for SSO between Social Engine and Magento 2. Go through the Link to find the solution http://www.ipragmatech.com/products/magento-socialengine-sso/

let me know if you have any queries.